# Controlling the speed of a jquery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I've been getting help with building this function from the community here, which I'm very thankful for - js newb. But there's something that I can't seem to figure out.

I have a relatively positioned div that slides into view when a trigger is hovered over. It subsequently pushes the content below said div down - perfect. The problem is I can't figure out how to control the speed of the div that being slid in. I can control other things, like say the speed of the opacity of the content in said div, but not how quickly that div appears.

If someone can be kind enough to explain how I can affect the speed of slide effect it would be greatly appreciated, as always.

Here's my markup:

```
<nav class="site-navigation" role="navigation">
    <div class="menu-1-container">
        <ul id="menu-1" class="menu">
            <li id="menu-item-1"> <a href="#">Releases</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="dropdown-contain">
    <p>Content</p>
</div>

<div class="other">
    <p>Other Content</p>
</div>
```

Here's some CSS:

```
.site-navigation {
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 25px 0;
}
.other {
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 25px;
}
.dropdown-contain {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100px;
}
```

And here's the jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on("mouseover", "#menu-item-1, .dropdown-contain", function () {
        $(".dropdown-contain").css({
            "display": "block"
        });
        $(".dropdown-contain").stop().animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 1000);
    });

    $(document).on("mouseleave", "#menu-item-1, .dropdown-contain", function () {
        $(".dropdown-contain").stop().animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 1000, function () {
            $(".dropdown-contain").css({
                "display": "none"
            });
        });
    });
});
```

And a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ericbrockman/BpETX/)**.

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Something like `slideToggle` will slide the content area down, and then fade in the text.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BpETX/4/)

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on("mouseenter", "#menu-item-1, .dropdown-contain", function () {
        $(".dropdown-contain").slideToggle(500, function() {
            $(this).fadeTo(500, 1);
        });
    });

    $(document).on("mouseleave", "#menu-item-1, .dropdown-contain", function () {
        $(".dropdown-contain").fadeTo(500, 0, function() {
            $(this).slideToggle(500);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Goose, that works well when I first hover over the trigger, but then when I move the cursor down over the content in the .dropdown-contain div it slides back up. Once I remove the cursor entirely the whole function seems to behave erratically and glitchy, sliding up and down at various speeds on it's own.

Comment: Note too, that I changed `mouseover` to `mouseenter` to fix that issue. If you need to, you can also add `.stop()` to help when the use mouses over/out quickly.

Comment: I added the .stop(), which helps, but it's still a bit erratic. Seems to work well if you just hover on the trigger and then leave the trigger moving your mouse up, but if you leave bringing your mouse down over the content it's still glitching out. Not sure if it helps to look at the live site http://ericbrockmanwebsites.com/